# Am I understanding right about the sigma algebra generated by random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have encountered many types of sigma algebra generated by a random variable. I would like to clarify my understanding of them.

The simplest one is generated by a random variable. I skip it here.
Then I have sigma algebra generated by any family of random variables. i.e. Suppose $X_i$s are rvs from $(\Omega, A)$ to $(E_i, \mathcal{E_i})$, $\sigma\left(\left(X_i\right)_{i \in I}\right)$ is defined as
$$\sigma\left(\left(X_i\right)_{i \in I}\right)=\sigma\left(\cup _{i \in I}\left\{X_i^{-1}\left(B_i\right): B_i \in \mathcal{E}_i\right\}\right)$$. It is the smallest such that any $X_i$ is measurable. It can be regarded as the smallest sigma algebra such that $\left(X_i\right)_{i \in I}$ as a random variable to the product space is measurable. (By the universal property below.)

($f$ is measurable iff $\pi_i \circ f$ is measurable for all $i$, $\pi_i$ is the projection map from the prdocut space to its $i$ coordinate, see below the diagram)
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
{} & {} & (E_i, \mathcal{E_i}) \\
{} & \overset{\pi_i \circ f}{\nearrow} & \uparrow \pi_i \\
(\Omega, A) & \underset{f}{\to} & (\prod E_i, \otimes\mathcal{E_i})
\end{array}
$$
**Right or wrong?**

> Special case (Index set is Countable), we have $\sigma(\cup_{1}^{\infty} (\sigma(X_i)) :=\sigma((X_i)_{i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, n, \cdots\}})=\sigma(\cup_{j=1}^{\infty} \sigma (X_1, \cdots, X_j))$

Proof: $\forall A \in \cup_{1}^{\infty} (\sigma(X_i))$, $\exists i$,such that $A=X_i^{-1} (B), B \in \mathcal{E_i}$, so $A \in \sigma(X_1, \cdots, X_i) \subset RHS$

$\forall A \in \cup_{j=1}^{\infty} \sigma (X_1, \cdots, X_j)$, $A \in \sigma (X_1, \cdots, X_k)=\sigma (\cup_{1}^{k} \sigma(X_i)) \subset LHS$

**Right or wrong?**